# Сравнение структуры списков

Tags: python, list

Стоит задача сравнить структуру списка, то есть расположения в нём списков, например,

```
a=[1,[1,1]]   
b=[2,[2,2]]
```

должно вернуть `True`, пока

```
a=[[1,1],1]  
b=[2,[2,2]]
```

должно вернуть `False`.

Была идея заменять все значения(за исключения списков) списками, но реализация не удалась, так как массивы могут быть многомерными.

Рад любым предложениям.

Comment: Мне кажется нужно идти параллельно по корневым спискам и сравнивать тип элементов. При обнаружении списка рекурсивно вызывать проверку вложенных списков и т.д. Если всё прошли то совпадение. Если где-то не совпал тип или один список оказался длиннее другого - значит не совпали.

Comment: спасибо, должно помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или в таком:

```
def chek(l1: list, l2: list):
    for idx, element in enumerate(l1):
        if type(element) != type(l2[idx]):
            return False
    return True
print(chek([1, [1, 1]], [[2, 2]]))
```

Comment: Кажется, не будет работать для `chek([], [1])`, ну и для `chek([1], ["2"])`

Comment: и для `chek([[1, [1]]], [[2, 2]])`

Answer (score 4):

Что-то в таком духе (с улучшениями от @CrazyElf):

```
def cmp_struct(lhs, rhs):
    if type(lhs) != list != type(rhs):
        return True
    elif type(lhs) == list == type(rhs) and len(lhs) == len(rhs):
        return all(cmp_struct(l, r) for l, r in zip(lhs, rhs))
    else:
        return False

print(cmp_struct([], []))                    # True
print(cmp_struct([1], []))                   # False
print(cmp_struct([1], [2]))                  # True
print(cmp_struct([1, []], [2]))              # False
print(cmp_struct([1, [2, 4]], [5, [1, 2]]))  # True
```

Comment: Сравнения с одним и тем же через `and` можно написать короче как двойное сравнение: `a == x and b == x` => `a == b == x`, неравенство можно так же укоротить, но общее значение нужно в середину написать. И не красивое с индексами `p[0]`, `p[1]` можно заменить на `for a, b in zip...`

Comment: @CrazyElf да, так будет лучше. А как неравенство упростить?

Comment: Уже понял,  сейчас поправлю все

Answer (score 2):

можно попробовать что-то наподобие этого, вроде работает как надо:

```
a=[1,[1,1],[22,3]] 
b=[2,[2,2],[3,44]]
c=[3,[1,1],[2,3,4]]

f = lambda x: str(x).translate(str.maketrans('','','0123456789'))

f(a)==f(b)  # True
f(a)==f(c)  # False
```

PS. здесь пример с целыми числами, но для строковых значений подход аналогичный.

**UPD**

этот вариант работает со всеми символами:

```
a=[1,[1,1],[22,'abc№123']] 
b=[2,[2,2],['3_2.5%',44]]

from re import sub

f = lambda x: sub(r'[^\[\],]','',str(x))

f(a)==f(b)  # True
```

Comment: Хорошая идея, я что-то такое думал как вариант, но не додумал

Comment: @CrazyElf, только сейчас понял, что если в строке будет символ запятой, то код сработает некорректно...